# How to integrate my own app in elgg

Tags: elgg

I would like to create a new widget(quiz) in Elgg where I can put my own content. I would like to have there all the default menus, etc. but with empty space where I can put my code.

The user should be able to view only their quiz based on the login. Should it be done as a new plugin? If yes, how to create empty page with my current template settings?